# My site got hacked and got many mirror sites which are copying original website

Tags: mirror

My site got hacked and cloned multiple times. Now if i post anything its get updated on all cloned sites. Can i use some code in such a way that if a user visits a cloned site, he is redirected to original one. Any modification in theme or htaccess file which could do the job. Any help would be 
appreciated. 
 I am using WordPress on shared hosting. My site is dlsoftfree.com and mirror sites are
zoodsabt.com

Thanks

Comment: Wrong place for this type of question, as this is for programming q&a. And, with what you provided, I really don't know what you're expecting as an answer, other than "shut down your web server."

Comment: This kind of question, without any example, neither url, how you can think anyone could answer to it precisely ?

Comment: Sorry for providing incomplete information. I am using WordPress on shared hosting. My site is dlsoftfree.com and mirror sites are 

http://ddi66.com/
http://zoodsabt.com/
http://shepardsnacks.com/
http://881df.com/
http://tickyourticket.com/
http://balanian.com/
http://la-m2.com/
http://83cc.net/
http://tempobet516.com/

Comment: So now you've included links to sites that are supposedly compromised? *Nobody* should click those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know it was a hacker and not a web crawling ?

Try a Javascript code in the middle of your article.

```
<script>
//replace 'example.com' for your domain
    if(! /^http[s]?:\/\/example.com\//.test(window.location.href)){
        var url = window.location.href.replace(/^http[s]?:\/\/([^:\/\s]+)(\w+)+\//, "http://example.com/");
        window.location.replace(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try this code in the new articles, if it's a web crawler, you will have to wait the time (wich may be unknow) of the crawler read your site again.

Comment: @ Bartolomeu S. Gusella. Code works but it also redirect original site as well. Like, it will redirect example.com/post-title to example.com . Kindly give modified version of code so that it should not redirect original site. Also urls pattern of cloned and original site are same, just change of domain name. Thanks

Comment: my site uses http and www, not https. site link is www.mixhax.com

Comment: I just want to ask if its possible to add whole code in some theme file like functions and its reference  may be used in post. Reference can be a class which if someone removes or domain is different then it  will redirect to original domain.

Comment: What I thinking is happening in your website is that a program acess your site read the article and insert in its own, if you put the redirect code in theme, most likely the "redirect code" won't be copied like the rest of the article and the redirect won't work

Comment: @bartolomeu-s-gusella I have a little request . Can you give a modified code such that if site address is mydomain.com/category1/post-url then it should redirect to mynewdomain.com/category1/post-url . you above code works fine for main domain but not for categories. I need that i should work on basis of categories name. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @Zain the code already do this at "replace". If it isn't working properly you should take a deeper look at clone site how the code is running maybe put a "debbuger" in your code to see how it reacts on cloned site.

Comment: @bartolomeu-s-gusella Okay thanks. I working fine now. Can i use this code in blogger as well. Like i have blog on google blogspot, can i use this code ? so that if anyone copies content, it should be redirected. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I think you can

Answer (score -1):

there is most probable a shell on the server a php file which they can go to via the browser which will give them access to any file on your server change your ftp info, your hosting login info, check all your files for different files which are not ment to be there.Your site is also linked to another when you click the posts it forwards you to another website.

Comment: Please don't litter this type of question with random suggestions. You don't even know what language the website is written in, or whether any php script is sitting around (as not a single detail was shared by the OP).The question itself is off-topic, and should be treated as such.

Comment: Please keep your comments respectful. No place for off-color language here.